# How to handle large number of small text files being converted to parquet files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have a pipe separated csv file of size 9 kb. Using pyspark, I am reading csv file and converting it to parquet file. The converted parquet file is of 22 kb.

1. Why parquet file taking up more space than original file even after compression? I know metadata will be added but its more than content size it self. Is there any known way to calculate or estimate size of metadata.
2. Issue which I understand is small file size. If I merge it to single file. Will it cause any performance or IO issues when reading big file instead of many small files in terms of parallel reading. What will be impact of no of partitions.

Comment: Read large number of files into a single dataframe. Then partition the dataframe into suitable number of paritions say 10-50. And then write out the parquet file. This is relevant here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098198/spark-how-to-specify-number-of-resulting-files-for-dataframe-while-after-writing